# jQuery Accordion Menu Items Remain Open Until Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a jQuery accordion menu but it doesn't seem to be acting in the default manner.  Basically, when I click on a menu item the item opens as expected.  However, when I click on a different menu item it also opens as expected but the first menu item remains open.  The jQuery documentation states:

"An accordion doesn't allow more than one content panel to be open at the same time, and it takes a lot of effort to do that."

I promise it took very little effort to break this default functionality ;).  Anyway, I have posted my JS, HTML and CSS on JSFiddle and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  Other than opening and closing it works fine, even though it doesn't appear to on JSFiddle.  Here's the link:  [JSFiddle Post](http://jsfiddle.net/stringman/9Jrqq/)

Thanks in advance.

Ken

Answer (score 0):

Can You Organize your output page in the way that I at least can see the menu clearly. Its difficult to access the them in your html

Comment: I did not check the jQuery UI 1.8.16 option.  The menu shows better now so maybe it will give you a better idea of the menu structure. I'm not sure why it doesn't show like on my workstation.